# Geofire not able to detect created database element on Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm working on this block of code where it stores geofire locations:

```
let geoFireRef = admin.database().ref().child('customer_requests');
let geoFireApp = new geofire.GeoFire(geoFireRef);
await geoFireApp.set(context.params.pushId, [original.pickup.lat, original.pickup.lng]);
```

and stucked on this error based on Firebase logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pieceNum_') at pathChild (/workspace/node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:5727:23)

I have this realtime database on firebase named "customer_requests":

[image]

And this is my rule configuration:

```
"customer_requests" : {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": true
},
```

Can someone please help my solve this error. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here's the values of pushId, pickup.lat, and pickup.lang

[image]

Comment: The rules and creation of GeoFire look fine at first glance, so most likely the problem comes from one of the values you pass. You might want to log your `context.params.pushId`, `original.pickup.lat`, and `original.pickup.lng` right before you pass them to `geoFireApp.set` and check if their values are what you expect.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please see updated question with included screenshot of the values of pushId, pickup.lat, and pickup.lng. They are what I expect to be written on "customer_requests". Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's going on. I hope somebody else spots the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by downgrading firebase and geofire versions. Thank you.