# Errors with Firebase based Ionic5 and Angular app - (possible exports: default, firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic5

I am trying to migrate/update an old ionic angular App. In the process I updated Angular from 12 to 13 and firebase from 8.3.1 to 8.10.1. I keep getting the errors below that I am not sure how to address.

```
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13761:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
[ng] 
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13821:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
[ng] 
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13835:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
[ng] 
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13837:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
[ng] 
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13900:23-29 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
[ng] 
[ng] ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:13901:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: default, firebase)
```

My ionic info output is as below

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1 (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.11
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.11
   @angular/cli                  : 13.3.11
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/android : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/core    : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/ios     : 5.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 3 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 2.0.0) : 1.7.4

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v20.2.0 (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin/node)
   npm     : 9.6.6
   OS      : macOS Unknown
   Xcode   : Xcode 15.0.1 Build version 15A507
```

Couldn't find anything related in my search. Appreciate any thoughts or pointers to help resolve this. #AskFirebase

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: Consider moving to the latest version of Firebase Client SDK?  Preferably not using the "compat" interface but moving to the modular API?

Comment: Thank you @GregFenton. I upgraded firebase to the latest on version i.e 9.23.0 and had to update geofire to 6.0.0. But in doing that I get the error below. And in looking to address it the link below suggests that I revert back

geoLocationService error =  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pieceNum_')
    at qt (geofire.min.js:590:980)
    at geofire.min.js:1299:1686
    at rt (geofire.min.js:361:2620)
    at Qr (geofire.min.js:1299:1645)
    at As (geofire.min.js:1397:3182)
    at e.set (geofire.min.js:1430:9558)

Comment: Link suggesting to revert is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326031/geofire-not-able-to-detect-created-database-element-on-firebase

So not quite sure how to resolve this. Appreciate any thoughts on this.